# Mercurial specify initial state for an unversioned file

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Is it possible to use Mercurial to specify the initial state of an unversioned file?

More specifically, I want this to work:

```
jonathan@dev-vm ~$ mkdir initial-state
jonathan@dev-vm ~$ cd initial-state/
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ hg init
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ touch main.cpp
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ touch config.cpp
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ hg add      
adding config.cpp
adding main.cpp
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ echo "config.cpp" > .hgignore
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ hg add
adding .hgignore
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ hg commit -m "initial commit"
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ echo "#define CONFIG true" >> config.cpp

# This is what I would like to see:
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ hg status
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$

# This is what happens:
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$ hg status
M config.cpp
jonathan@dev-vm ~/initial-state$
```

Comment: Why exactly would you want that?

Comment: So I can create local config files with default content.

Comment: No, I mean why would you not want to see them in the status?

Comment: Well, it's not that I don't want them to show up in the status, it's that I don't want changes to get committed to the repo after the initial clone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I configure Mercurial to not commit specific config files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674542/how-do-i-configure-mercurial-to-not-commit-specific-config-files)

Comment: You mean you want the files to be added to the repository at repository creation time, but not tracked after that? If so, no, you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is commit the initial version of `main.cpp` before adding `main.cpp` to `.hgignore`. The reason `main.cpp` still shows up on `hg status` is that because it is listed in `.hgignore` when you do the first commit, the first commit does not actually commit the changes to `main.cpp` (the initial version).

So, rather:

```
% hg init
% touch main.cpp
% hg add main.cpp
% hg ci -m "Initial commit"
% echo "main.cpp" >.hgignore
% hg add .hgignore
% hg ci -m "Update hg ignore"
% echo "wotnot" >main.cpp
% hg status
# you should see nothing
```

Having said that, putting `main.cpp` in `.hgignore` will not prevent future commits to the file. The file can be changed and commit by doing something like: `hg ci -m "commit main.cpp" main.cpp`